# Roll up 1 column using function in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to roll up a table in DAX as seen below. It's just some operations. I can do this in SQL with joins or in Power Query with merges or pivots, however I was just wondering if this is possible using DAX. Would this even be a good idea? Would it better to perform such an operation using SQL/Power Query/Python/R?

| name | type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | a | 5 |
| t1 | b | 10 |
| t1 | c | 5 |
| t2 | a | 5 |
| t2 | b | 5 |
| t2 | c | 10 |

f : (a + b)/c

| name | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| t1 | 15/5 |
| t2 | 10/10 |

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly fine and simple calculation for DAX.

```
F = DIVIDE( CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[quantity]),'Table'[type] IN {"a","b"}),
            CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[quantity]),'Table'[type] = "c") )
```

Always use [DIVIDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-divide-function-operator) when there is a chance that the divisor ("c") could be 0.
Use [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sum-function-dax) just like you would in Excel, but wrap it in a [CALCULATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) if you need to filter values first. Use [IN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-operator-reference#logical-operators) if you have a list of values to filter for the same column.